Derivation of the Bessel Functions of Half Order for (p= 1/2) from the General Solution of Bessel's Differential Equation.
When $( p = \frac{1}{2} )$, equation $$ u'' + \left( 1 + \frac{1 - 4p^2}{4x^2} \right) u = 0;
$$ shows that the general solution of Bessel’s equation is expressible in either of the equivalent forms:
$
y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \left( c_1 \cos x + c_2 \sin x \right)
$
and
$
y = c_1 J_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) + c_2 J_{-\frac{1}{2}}(x).
$
It therefore must be true that
$
\sqrt{x} J_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) = a \cos x + b \sin x
$
and
$
\sqrt{x} J_{-\frac{1}{2}}(x) = c \cos x + d \sin x
$
for certain constants ( a ), ( b ), ( c ), and ( d ). By evaluating these constants, show that
$
J_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}} \sin x
$
and
$
J_{-\frac{1}{2}}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}} \cos x.
$
